# How to get newest data from Elasticsearch based on a date field

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I implemented a scheduled script that inject date into my Elasticsearch. The script doesn't check if the data exist already in Elasticsearch so it inserts duplications. What I want is to get all events that have the latest timestamp field value (insertion dateTime).

Note: I don't have an id or a unique field that can help me group by it and set size to 1 to get the latest.

So can you give some other options?

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate by the latest available timestamp and get the top, potentially duplicate docs like so:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "latest": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        },
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but I am limited by the infra team to not put more than 100 in the size of top_hits, and I have much more rows to get.

Comment: Hmm you didn't say you've got a limit. If you wanna get `get all events`, you'll need to ask your infra colleagues to let you increase it.